# Translating checkbox labels

Tags: templating, localization, globals, checkboxes, label

I'm trying to translate the labels for a global checkbox field in my front-end templates like in this post: [Is there a way to have checkbox field labels translatable?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13709/is-there-a-way-to-have-checkbox-field-labels-translatable). 
This looked promising but I can't seem to get it working (maybe it's Craft2 and things have changed in 3)

Basically it's using namespacing in the translations file e.g for a French translation file

```
return [
  'field.fruits.option.apple.label' => 'pomme',
  'field.fruits.option.lemon.label' => 'citron',
];
```

But no translations showing in the template when I try

```
{% for fruit in myGlobalSet.fruits %}
    {{ fruit.label|t }}
{% endfor %}
```

Any ideas? I'm sure it must be syntax related or wrong namespacing but I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do the namespaced trick in Craft 3, you'd do it like this:

Create your folder structure like this for your locale with one file for the Control Panel and one for the front-end of the site:

[image]

Contents of files:

[image]

Settings for Checkbox field:

[image]

Template code:

[image]

Front-end results:

[image]

Edit entry results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brad. I'm using static translations successfully elsewhere in the site but for my particular use case (slightly more complex than fruits) I'm wanting to drill down more specifically and translate _only_ the checkbox field's labels based on their value. That's why the post I referenced was interesting. Is it at all possible to do it the namespacing way in Craft3?

Comment: Updated answer.